# Математическая переменная в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика

Можно ли создать такую числовую переменную,  значение которой можно будет объявить позже, либо вообще не объявлять? При этом она смогла бы свободно участвовать в математических выражениях, а ещё лучше, чтобы можно было бы определить её значение, с помощью уравнения.
Например если `x + 2 = 8`, то `x = 6`

Если это невозможно, то так и ответьте.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [Sympy](https://pythonist.ru/biblioteka-sympy-simvolnye-vychisleniya-v-python/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решаем уравнения с помощью модуля [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) (устанавливаем с помощью команды `pip install sympy`)

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x

# Если нужна какая-то нестандартная переменная, например, не однобуквенная,
# которой нет в модуле sympy.abc то создаете ее через sympy.symbol:
# wtf = sympy.symbol("wtf")

# Переносим все в одну сторону, чтобы с другой стороны получилось 0:
# x + 2 - 8 = 0
# Все что перенесли превращаем в функцию

func = x + 2 - 8

# Решаем уравнение func(x) = 0
results = sympy.solve(func)

# Выводим все корни
print(results)  # [6]
```

Выведется список с одним элементом.

Аналогично можно, например, решать и квадратные уравнения (и другие типы уравнений), но правда в отличие от того что учат в школе, квадратные уравнения будут давать всегда два корня - либо действительные, либо комплексные:

```
func = x ** 2 - 4
results = sympy.solve(func)
print(results)  # [-2, 2]
```

```
func = x ** 2 + 4
results = sympy.solve(func)
print(results)  # [-2*I, 2*I]
```